# My cookies are not being transmitted when using webtest.TestApp

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webtest

I am confused as to how to pass cookies in a request using python webtest.

I have the following test:

```
def test_commenting_and_voting(self):
    https = {'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https'}
    users = []
    for user in USERS:
      resp_post = self.testapp.post_json('/user', user)
      users.append(resp_post.json.get('id'))

    self.testapp.post_json('/login/%s' % users[0],
                           {'password' : USERS[0]['password']},
                           extra_environ=https)
    print "testapp's view of the cookiejar"
    print self.testapp.cookies
    print "END"
    resp_post = self.testapp.post_json('/comment', {'value': ""})
```

and the following handler:

```
class CommentHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, id=None):
        get_from_urlsafe(self, id)

    @ndb.transactional
    def post(self, id=None):
        assert False, self.request.cookies
```

I am raising an error from the handler function in order to see the cookies. It appears that the cookies, although in the cookiejar within the `webtest.TestApp` side of things, are not being transmitted when making the wsgi request. So how do I get the cookies to transmit?

```
Using scent:
test_commenting_and_voting (test_models.test_Models) ... 
testapp's view of the cookiejar
{'secret': '58bd5cfd36e6f805de645e00f8bea9d70ae5398ff0606b7fde829e6732394bb7', 'session': 'agx0ZXN0YmVkLXRlc3RyIgsSD1VzZXJFbnRpdHlHcm91cBgBDAsSB1Nlc3Npb24YCww'}
END
WARNING:root:suspended generator transaction(context.py:941) raised AssertionError(<RequestCookies (dict-like) with values {}>)
ERROR:root:<RequestCookies (dict-like) with values {}>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stephen/bin/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  ... I removed some of the stacktrace here ....
  File "/home/stephen/work/seocomments/src/python/main.py", line 127, in post
    assert False, self.request.cookies
AssertionError: <RequestCookies (dict-like) with values {}>
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 6 tests in 0.371s

FAILED (errors=1)
Failed - Back to work!
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind. The reason I wasn't seeing the cookies was that the cookies were being set as secure cookies, which means they only exist when using a secure connection. My test was using a insecure connection.

To make this work, change the request to the following:

```
self.testapp.post_json('/comment', 
                       {'value': ""}, 
                       extra_environ={'wsgi.url_scheme': 'https'})
```

Comment: You can pass the extra_environ to the testapp when you create it, so you don't have to do it on every request.

Comment: Thanks for adding your own answer, Stephen - I had the exact same problem and the exact same solution. Would have taken me a long time to figure it out.